# Python - checking over an open file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
BALLOTS CAST
Riding 0
YES YES NO YES
NO NO NO NO 
.
.
.
YES NO YES YES

Riding 1
YES NO NO YES
NO NO YES NO 
.
.
.
YES YES YES YES
```

and so on.  I have the user's input for the riding number called `riding`, and then I need to make a list of the votes for that riding.  For example, if the riding choice is 0, then I need a list `[[YES YES NO YES], [NO NO NO NO], ..., [YES NO YES YES]]`.

I need to figure out a way to use `readline()` and the `while` loop.  Here's roughly what I have:

```
ballots = open(FILENAME, 'r')
line = ballots.readline().rstrip()
L = []
i = 0
if riding.isdigit():
    while i < ???:
        line = ballots.readline().rstrip()
        i += 1
        if line == 'Riding ' + riding:
            while line != '\n':
                L.append(line.rstrip().split())
```

but I just get an empty list.  I also tried this with `180` instead of `???` because that's how many lines there are, but I don't know what to actually put in its place.  I tried `max(enumerate(ballots))[0]` but it empties the `ballots` list completely (or somehow else makes everything empty).

Can anyone point out my errors and what I should change?  As I said, I have to use `readline()` and `while` and I can't import anything.

Also, the reason I put `if riding.isdigit()` is because there is also the option to choose `all` ridings.  It works:

```
if riding == 'all':
    line = ballots.readline().rstrip()
    for line in ballots:
        if line[0:6] != 'Riding' and line != '\n':
            L.append(line.rstrip().split())
```

the only problem is I can't figure out how to use the `while` loop instead of the `for` loop...

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a state variable to detect when you should read lines, and when you are done just `break` the loop:

```
lines = []
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as ballots:
    foundriding = False
    ballots.next()  # skip first line
    for line in ballots:
        if line.rstrip() == 'Riding ' + riding:
            foundriding = True
            continue
        if not foundriding: 
            continue
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line and not line.startswith('Riding '):
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
```

The above code will skip all lines until it finds the correct `Riding <number>` line, at which point it'll set `foundriding` to True. Once the flag is set, it'll add all subsequent lines to `lines` until it finds an empty line or another that starts with `Riding`. At that point it'll break the reading loop.

Another alternative is to use [`itertools.takewhile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as ballots:
    ballots.next()  # skip first line
    for line in takewhile(lambda l: l.rstrip() != 'Riding ' + riding, ballots):
        pass  # skip lines
    lines = [l.rstrip() for l in takewhile(lambda l: l.rstrip() and not l.startswith('Riding '), ballots)]
```

`takewhile` will take lines from ballots until the test returns False. After that, we can take more lines with a different test, namely that the line is not empty and doesn't start with `Riding`.

Neither solution needs to read the whole file. We stop reading when we found the correct riding and all it's votes have been read into `lines`.

I use the `ballots` file object like an iterator. That's not quite the same method as `.readline()`; if `.readline()` is a hard requirement (uhoh, teachers and homework), you can turn `ballot.readline()` into an iterator too:

```
ballotiterator = iter(ballots.readline, '')
```

then use `ballotiterator` instead of `ballots` wherever you see `for line in ballots`, `ballots.next()` or `takewhile(..., ballots)`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Pickle: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle
It is very useful for saving and restoring python objects to files, e.g. lists.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but OP just asked about for loop to while loop conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using regular expressions:

```
import re
with open("test.txt") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
    if riding.isdigit():
        section = re.search(r"(?sm)^Riding " + riding + r".*?(?=Riding|\Z)", text)
        matches = re.findall(r"(?:(?:YES|NO) ?)+", section.group(0))
        result = [s.split() for s in matches]
        print(result)
```

With `riding` set to `"1"`, this results in

```
[['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES'], ['NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO'], ['YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES']]
```

Of course, you might want to use

```
result = [[True if value == "YES" else False for value in s.split()] 
                                             for s in matches]
```

instead, in order to get

```
[[True, False, False, True], [False, False, True, False], [True, True, True, True]]
```

No error checking is done (e. g. whether a segment labeled `Riding x` is present in the input file at all), but that can be added trivially.

Comment: OP wanted to use the while loop and understand it. The solution you are offering is good, but seems like not relevant.